# Moving a navbar when encapsulation is at none

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular for a school project and I am trying to create a nav bar with tabs to different pages.

My problem is on the CSS, I would like to change the color of the nav bar AND change the position of the nav bar.

I manage to do both those things, but not at the same time : if I have `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in my `@Component` of my 'topbar.component.ts' I can change the style of the nav bar, but I can't change its position (things like position, align, etc. do nothing).
But if `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` is not present, I can change the position of my nav bar but not the style.

I presume that I don't know what to call in the css to move it correctly when I change the encapsulation.

Here is the `@Component` with the encapsulation :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-topbar',
  templateUrl: './topbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topbar.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Here is what the nav bar look like in the HTML :

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link
       *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
       [routerLink]="link.link"
       routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
       [active]="rla.isActive">
      {{link.label}}
    </a>
  </nav>
```

Here is the CSS :

```css
/* label style */
.mat-tab-link{
  color: #EFEFEF;
}

/* Styles for the ink bar */
.mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar{
  background: #EFEFEF;
}
```

So here I can change the font color, background color, etc.
But any changment in the positioning do nothing.

Is there a tag (I don't know if this is the correct name, I am quite bad in Angular, HTML and CSS) that I can use to change the position of the nav bar when I put the encapsulation at none? Like `.mat-tab-nav-bar.bar-position` or something?

I feel like I really miss something simple here, but I didn't find any result for my specific case on the internet.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please provide an example via https://stackblitz.com/ 
From what I read it seems like you need to make use of `ngAfterViewChecked()` hook. But I can confirm after you've provided the example

Comment: Thanks, I tryed to do stuff with stackblitz, but I never used this site. I don't manage to do what I want, it print error in my imports when I try to redo what I've done with the navbar. What do yo uexactly want to see?

Comment: use this stackblitz to crete your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wxdsrn
if your imports dont work it is probably because you need to add the npm dependencies on the left sidebar. 
what I wanted to achieve with this is that you provide a minimal example. it should make it easier for other to help you